# Does `Resolve` not work with exponents?

Tags: resolve

I do not think I truly understand how `Resolve` is working despite reading the documentation and various posts on this stack exchange. For example, why is this expression not evaluating to true

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x, n}, x > 0 && n > 1,  Positive[x^n] ]]
```

Is there some constraint that I am not thinking about? The above expression evaluates to

$\forall _{\{x,n\},x>0\land n>1}x^{n}>0$

which is just a restatement of the problem.

Comment: Fractional powers can give you complex numbers?

Comment: @wxffles not for $k>0$, roots of positive numbers are positive

Comment: `Simplify[x^n > 0, x > 0 && n > 1]` works ... I don't know why Resolve doesn't.

Comment: @MHH  Roots of positive numbers are not always positive.  Consider, `Solve[y^3 == x, y]`, which yields `{{y -> x^(1/3)}, {y -> -(-1)^(1/3) x^(1/3)}, {y -> (-1)^(2/3) x^(1/3)}}`.  On the other hand, it is true that the Mathematica function `Power[x, 1/3]` returns only the positive root.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, My statement was of the form of: the square root or cube root etc. of a positive number is always positive. I was using root colloquially as the fractional power operator not as the root of a function.